# Migrating from DotNetCore to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js

We wrote an application in Dotnetcore using WebAPIs. Now, we would like to migrate to NodeJS for a client because their IT team support NodeJS.

I am wondering if someone has any reasons/advantages of moving away from Dotnetcore and write API's in NodeJS?

Comment: Too broad and opinion based

Comment: **I respect your opinion, please share if you have a perspective**

Comment: Question is too opinion base. And my opinion is - there is no reason to move to NodeJS. In both cases consumers of your API will use HTTP! Who ever cares what works on the back-end under the hood?

Comment: Close this question or make it more concrete. Right now there could not be correct answer.  This question sounds like `what is better - birds or dogs?`

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a pertinent question. For me, there are a few reasons to use node.js over .NET Core:

- **a single language** - Having a single language on both the client and server increases code reuse which reduces development time, maintenance and bugs.
  It also prevents developers from having to jump back and forth
  between two paradigms which can be annoying.
- **a better ecosystem** - node.js has an extremely vibrant community with thousands upon thousands of well supported packages and test
  frameworks. There is also a better crossplatform IDE thanks to Jetbrains/Webstorm. Currently there isn't Visual Studio for Linux and Visual Studio Code is pretty bare-bones.
- **networking** - node's network apis are beautiful and easy to use. Spinning up a socket or web server in a couple lines of code is priceless to
  me. Networking in C# is not nearly as elegant.
- **maturity** - its first commits to Github were around mid
  2009 and is used in production worldwide and currently has reliable LTS builds. While .NET Core leverages an existing and mature .NET Framework code base, it isn't the same thing and fairly untested in the wild.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: Sorry for being rude, but we can see an answer from another Node.js geek! Let the holy-shitty-war begin!

Comment: On the contrary, I think C# is a beautiful language. I use it everyday at work and it was a great effort to bring .NET Core to the open source community. I just think node.js has a few advantages over it.

Comment: The Only argument that you may rise in favor to Node.JS is isomorphic applications.

Answer (score 4):

As it is purely opinion based question, I as a .NET developer with 9+ years of experience will say - "No, it is a very stupid move to migrate to NodeJS!". We can see that 2-3 years ago was a big-bang of NodeJS, everyone was planning to migrate to NodeJS. But now we can see that a lot of them are migrating back to Java/.NET.

I will be an opposer to `mr.freeze` and ruin his arguments:

- **a single language** argument. It doesn't make sense since we have a swagger, who cares what is on a backend?
- **a better ecosystem** . Very, very, very opinion based argument. While .NET is a commercial product of huge Microsoft company you know that someone takes responsibility for the product, while modules of Node.JS can be written by `drunk developer with hands from the wrong place from far-far village`. And about the argument about cross-platform IDE - who from .NET developers ever cares about that linux/unix? Even if cares there is Visual studio code. :)
- **Networing**. Not a argument at all, since everybody have his own understanding of word - `beautiful`
- **Maturity**. Not an argument as well, I've built 3 project using .NET core and it is working like a charm